# Compare strings of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work in a table in Postgresql. One column  hast first names, one columns has the full address of people including sometimes first names. I want to find all the rows where the entry from the first name column is in the second column.

Example

```
| id | firts_name   | address   |
|---|--------|------------------------|
| 1 | anna   | anna miller street 1   |
| 2 | bob    | b. smith street 2      |
| 3 | charly | charly wilson street 3 |
```

I want to return column  1 and 3

I tried this

```
select id, first_name, address from table1
where first_name ~ address
```

The result I  get is always empty.

Comment: Did you mean `... where address ~ first_name`?

Comment: Oh jeez. I just spent 30 min trying to work that out and googling and its just that. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm voting to close as it clearly is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Tilde (`~`) is the regular expression match operator; in your case you can probably use a simple pattern match operator `~~` (or `LIKE`), and you do need to create a pattern for matching by adding wildcard symbols:

```
select id, first_name, address from table1
where address ~~ concat('%', first_name, '%')
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d628e1ff9b9b15ff8720ecca3b231089)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that the operands of `~` are reversed. It's `target_string ~ pattern`, not vice versa.

I.e.:

```
select id, first_name, address from table1
where address ~ first_name;
```

However, this interprets the contents of `first_name` as a regular expression. This will produce unexpected results if `first_name` contains characters that are special in regexes, such as `*`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `+`, ...

If you just want to do a plain string search, you can do:

```
select id, first_name, address from table1
where position(first_name in address) > 0;
```

[[Live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3acb7/5/0)]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use regular expressions, `like` might be simpler:

```
select id, first_name, address
from table1
where address like '%' || first_name || '%';
```

One advantage of `like` over regular expressions is that Postgres will sometimes use indexes for it.  However, I don't think it will when the patter is variable as in this case.